# How can I "manually" move an existing discussion to chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I'd like to move an existing discussion, that consists so far of just a few comments, to chat instead of deleting the comments that are off topic to the issue of the question.

Can something like this be done? And if so how does it work? Or should I just flag the first comment I´d like to move for moderator attention and ask the mods to move the discussion starting with this comment?

It once happend that a discussion I was taking part in was *automatically* moved to chat but now I'd like to know if it can be done *manually* too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it cannot be done manually, not even by moderators, despite being a popular request on MSO ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat), etc.). Unless and until we get this feature implemented, you have a couple of options:

- Just post a comment asking to continue the discussion in the chat room (you can either use the site's main chat room or create a new chat room)
- Or keep the discussion going in the comments until the system gives you the automatic "move to chat" option. After you do that you can flag the first comment for a moderator to delete them.